# Laravel 8 getting count through three linked models

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent

I have a simple laravel 8 setup with three models:

- Student, that belongsTo a Major and hasMany groups
- Major, that hasMany students, and
- Group, that hasMany students.

Groups have a "course_year" column that is an integer between 1 and 7 including.
I'm creating an Index page to list all the Majors, and I want to display the count of students, that are in each year.

Here's the catch - as students can belong to many groups, some of the groups can belong to different course year, which I need to count, but they also can belong to several groups of the same year, that I don't want to count.

The result should be the number of individual students, that are enlisted in all groups in course_year, irrespective if they are enlisted in groups with another course_year.

Thanks for all the insights!

Comment: Have you tried the aggregate part of the official documentation ? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#aggregating-related-models 
You can define counting relationship on your models and load them like other relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to ZarkDev for pointing me to the right place in the docs. Was wondering around them a bit. I finally did this in my Major model, and it works:

```
public function students_major_count($major_id, $course_year) {
    $students = Student::withCount([
        'groups' => function ($query) use ($course_year) {
        $query->where('course', $course_year);
    }
    ])->where('major_id', $major_id)->get();
    return $students->where('groups_count', '>', 0)->count();
}
```

This way I'm counting each individual student enlisted in any amount of groups only once per course_year.

I'm happy to hear any additional suggestions on optimizing it, but it's working good enough.